# HikariCP trying to obtain connection to pool with different user id than provided

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hikaricp

I have a Java app (running Java 11) using HikariCP v3.3.1, with MySQL Connector/J version 8.0.17.  I have specified username = 'foo' and password = 'password' and Hikari opens up a connection to the DB with these credentials.  This all works.

There is a problem that I see in my logs, however.  I have debugging enabled for Hikari and I see stack traces like so:

```
2019-09-10 01:35:13.452 DEBUG 4941 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Cannot acquire connection from data source

java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 10 times. Giving up.
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:897) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:822) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:447) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:237) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$100(HikariPool.java:71) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:727) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:713) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJException: Access denied for user 'administrator'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

It looks like it is trying to open a connection in the pool with user = 'administrator'.  This naturally fails - because there is no such user in the database.

My question is this:  why did Hikari open up one connection successfully to the db with user = 'foo' and password = 'password' but then try to open another connection with a different user = 'administrator'?  'administrator' by the way is the name of user that is running the Java process.

Here is the datasource bean. No other data source bean defined, I think.

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties
public DataSource myDataSource() {
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    config.setJdbcUrl(dburl);
    config.setUsername(dbuser);
    config.setPassword(password);
    return new HikariDataSource(config);
}
```

The datasource - as I mentioned does get created with the correct username and password.

We get the values of the various attributes `dburl` and `dbuser`  from `@Value` declarations that pull values from the properties files as follows:

```
@Value("${myorg.dburl}"
String dburl;
@Value("${myorg.dbusername"}"
String dbuser;
String password; //this comes from cloud secret store per org policy
```

The application properties has the following relevant lines

```
myorg.dbhost=localhost
myorg.dburl=jdbc:mysql://${myorg.dbhost}:3306/jobs?useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10&useServerPrepStmts=false&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
myorg.dbusername=axcode
```

Thanks in advance!

Updated with new user experiment.  So it gets even more curious.  I created a new user on my Linux server 'foouser' - and ran the identical spring boot fat jar app.  And, it works correctly with no exceptions thrown.   Here is what I see from the periodic Hikari logs:

```
2019-09-12 12:30:46.685 DEBUG 3280 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
2019-09-12 12:31:16.685 DEBUG 3280 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
```

But when I run same app as 'administrator', then I see only 1 connection made to the db and an exception thrown when Hikari tries to open a second connection this time as user 'administrator'

```
2019-09-12 12:37:31.195 DEBUG 3514 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=1, active=0, idle=1, waiting=0)
2019-09-12 12:37:46.091 DEBUG 3514 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Cannot acquire connection from data source
```

Comment: Can you show datasource configuration? Did you define another datasource bean?

Comment: @user7294900 - I have updated to include the datasource configuration.    You bring up an interesting point - who/what would have instantiated another bean with default configuration?  Is there a way to check this?   Thanks much!

Comment: @user7294900 - I just double checked and printed out beans - and checked - there are no other datasources other than the one I created above.

Comment: Can you show datasource configuration in properties?

Comment: @user7294900 - done added those properties.

Comment: Don't you have `spring.datasource.username` or `spring.datasource.hikari.username` or similar properties?

Comment: @user7294900   No, I don't.  This is why this is mysterious.  My theory/speculation:   Somewhere Spring/Hikari wants to add a connection. It's not finding the user.  So it appears to be default user who is running the process?  In my case administrator?

Comment: @user7294900 - i added the results of an experiment i performed - i created a brand new linux user on the same system and ran the spring boot fat jar app.  It works - with all 10 connections created correctly.   But same app when run under 'administrator' fails with only 1 connection created correctly - and exception thrown when 2nd connection is attempted to be created...Stumped....